# My react app doesn't calculate properly (only after second symbol renders result)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react app. It has a button Add to add line to calculate volume. Every line contains 2 input fields for values of thickness and surface area correspondingly.
I noticed if thickness was inputted and user is starting to enter surface area, the volume will be rendered only after second symbol.

For example, thickness - inputted 100, surface - 1 and volume 0 (but expected 0,1). Then surface - 10 and volume 1 (as expected). The same if input surface 100 and thickness 1 --> volume 0 (expected 0,1).

Could someone explain how to fix the issue, please? Thank you for you help.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-lehmann-26k4y)

```
import { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (index) => (event) => {
    let currentValue = +event.target.value;
    if (event.target.name === "thickness") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], thickness: currentValue };
      if (datas[index].thickness && datas[index].surface) {
        newArr[index] = {
          ...newArr[index],
          volume: (currentValue * newArr[index].surface) / 1000,
        };
      }
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "surface") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], surface: currentValue };
      if (datas[index].thickness && datas[index].surface) {
        newArr[index] = {
          ...newArr[index],
          volume: (newArr[index].thickness * currentValue) / 1000,
        };
      }
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
  };
  const removeItem = (index) => {
    let newItems = datas.filter((product, id) => id !== index);
    setDatas(newItems);
  };
  const addLine = () => {
    setDatas([
      ...datas,
      {
        thickness: 0,
        surface: 0,
        volume: 0,
      },
    ]);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {datas.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <input
              label="thickness mm"
              name="thickness"
              id={index}
              value={data.thickness}
              onChange={handleChange(index)}
            />

            <input
              name="surface"
              label="surface m¬2"
              id={index}
              value={data.surface}
              onChange={handleChange(index)}
            />
            <span>Volume {data.volume}</span>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(index)}>X</button>
          </li>
        );
      })}

      <button onClick={addLine}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your conditions, you are checking if the old values are full instead of checking `newArr or currentValue` variables.

This is an example:
If we give `thickness` the value `100` when the user starts entering the `input surface`, you check if the variable datas[index].surface (old value) is full instead of checking the current value.

```
 const handleChange = (index) => (event) => {
    let currentValue = +event.target.value;
    if (event.target.name === "thickness") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], thickness: currentValue };
      if (newArr[index].thickness && newArr[index].surface) { //you should verify the latest values not old
        newArr[index] = {
          ...newArr[index],
          volume: (currentValue * newArr[index].surface) / 1000
        };
      }
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "surface") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], surface: currentValue };
      if (newArr[index].thickness && newArr[index].surface) { //you should verify the latest values not old
        newArr[index] = {
          ...newArr[index],
          volume: (newArr[index].thickness * currentValue) / 1000
        };
      }
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-liskov-dghgu?file=/src/App.js:99-939

Comment: Thank you so so much for the solution.

Comment: It will be helpful, If you can check the answer.